# Perl parsing file content

Tags: perl, parsing

I am trying to parse text file content consists of 3 categories and access it in the main code. I got to know that hash maybe a good way but since no columns in the input file is unique (Name could be repeatedly or different), I doubt is there other way to do it. Appreciate any reply.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; 
use warnings;

my $file = "/path/to/text.txt";
my %info = parseCfg($file);
#get first line data in text file (Eric cat xxx)
#get second line data in text file (Michelle dog yyy)
#so on

}

sub parseCfg {
    my $file = shift;
    my %data;
    return if !(-e $file);
    open(my $fh, "<", $file) or die "Can't open < $file: $!";
    my $msg = "-I-: Reading from config file: $file\n";
    while (<$fh>) {
        if (($_=~/^#/)||($_=~/^\s+$/)) {next;}
        my @fields = split(" ", $_);
        my ($name, $son, $address) = @fields;
        #return something
    }
    close $fh;
}
```

Input file format:(basically 3 columns)

```
#Name pet address    
Eric cat xxx
Michelle dog yyy
Ben horse zzz
Eric cat aaa
```

Answer (score 3):

The question isn't clear how the data will be used in the code.

Following code sample demonstrates how the data can be read and stored in anonymous hash referenced by `$href`. Then `$href` stored in anonymous array referenced in `$aref` which returned by `parse_cnf()` subroutine.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $fname = 'pet_data.txt';
my $data  = parse_cnf($fname);

say Dumper($data);

printf "Name: %-12s Pet: %-10s Address: %s\n", $_->@{qw/name pet address/} for $data->@*;

exit 0;

sub parse_cnf {
    my $fname = shift;  
    my $aref;
    
    open my $fh, '<', $fname
        or die "Couldn't open $fname";
        
    while( <$fh> ) {
        next if /(^\s*$|^#)/;
        my $href->@{qw/name pet address/} = split;
        push $aref->@*, $href;
    }
    
    close $fh;
    
    return $aref;
}
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'address' => 'xxx',
            'pet' => 'cat',
            'name' => 'Eric'
          },
          {
            'pet' => 'dog',
            'name' => 'Michelle',
            'address' => 'yyy'
          },
          {
            'name' => 'Ben',
            'pet' => 'horse',
            'address' => 'zzz'
          },
          {
            'address' => 'aaa',
            'pet' => 'cat',
            'name' => 'Eric'
          }
        ];

Name: Eric         Pet: cat        Address: xxx
Name: Michelle     Pet: dog        Address: yyy
Name: Ben          Pet: horse      Address: zzz
Name: Eric         Pet: cat        Address: aaa
```